# How to pause and start a process in regular intervals while other process keeps running in background

Tags: bash, shell

I have a case to implement where a baseline process keeps running in background.

There is another process which runs in regular intervals as a spike and then sleeps for some time and then again starts for a total of n iterations.

Code:

```
#start the baseline process in background
Command_1 & 
#Get the pid of the baseline process
pid1=$!
    i=0;
     #n iterations here is 2
    while [ $i -le 2 ]
    do  
        Command_2 &
        #PID of second command
        pid2=$!
        #Wait until the process which spikes in between finishes
        wait $pid2
        i=$((i+1))
        sleep 2
    done
    wait $pid1
```

This does not work as expected and described above. Please suggest what needs to be changed to make it working.

Comment: What do you expect? What does this do instead?

Comment: could a supervisor help? https://immortal.run/post/retries/  can stop/start/retrie,  start if other processes are up and running, or start only if the output of a command exit 0

Comment: @chepner It just executes the command 2 multiple time and then exits. It should rather keep the baseline running in background and then spikes a process multiple times in regular interval.

Comment: @nbari immortal will keep the command run forever which then needs to be manually killed by the user and not from the script.

Comment: `Command_1` *should* stay running in your example; nothing kills it, so if it exits, it's because it completed. Do you want  `Command_1` to restart when it exits? You can just replace `Command_1 &` with something like `while :; do Command_1; done & pid1=$!`

Comment: @ArchitGoyal true, unless you remove the `run.yml` from your script when done and that will finish the full process